# .First() with an anonymous function to access multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-function

I want to use an anonymous function inside of `.First()` but there must be another extension out there that I should be using for this, as `.First()` is expecting a `predicate`.

Basically, want to update multiple properties at once, very similar to using an anonymous function in a `.ForEach()`.

Anyone got the knowledge drop for me?

Ex:

```
//what i could do, but don't want to do
var person = people.First();
person.FirstName = "john";
person.LastName = "doe";

//where I am currently at, but can only access 1x property at a time
people.First().FirstName = "john";

//what I would like to do  
 people.First(x => {
    x.FirstName = "john";
    x.LastName = "doe";
});

//pattern im copying
people.ForEach(fe => {
    Console.WriteLine(fe.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(fe.LastName);
});
```

**Update**
I'm convinced that the original approach is the best. Thanks all for your help and guidance.

Comment: What is whrong with calling `First()` and than set the properties one after the other? Any different approach would just make your code worse readable and cluttered.

Comment: LINQ is for *querying* items, not for mutating them.  `First` *gives you the first item*, it doesn't perform some action(s) on the first item.  If you want to perform some action(s) on the first item then get the first item, then perform those actions on it.

Comment: The first bit of code is fine. Don't add syntactic sugar for the sake of it, add sugar if it makes the code more readable and robust. In this case, it does not.

Comment: I don't really see why you don't want to do the first part, it's the only correct version, you get an object to the local scope, and then you manipulate that object

Comment: Okay, removing the misuse of LINQ in my question, do any of you know of a good path forward? @HimBromBeere I think its cleaner, but just my opinion

Comment: [Recommended reading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `a good path forward` other than what we have already said which is to use the first block of code you showed.

Comment: @markokstate If you want to write that bad code, then write that bad code.  What's stopping you?

Comment: @Servy well, it appears there is no way to write it. =D

Comment: You can't  use LINQ to write it.  If you want to write your own method that does it, then write your own method that does it (and face the wrath of your co-workers).  We can't stop you from writing that bad code if you really want to.  You know it's a bad idea, and apparently don't care.

Comment: Yes, each comment has clearly let me know that I'm a buffoon and cannot use LINQ. We're past that. But really what I'm taking away from this is that even .ForEach() is bad practice too?

Comment: You can do it like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dznpgi but i'm not recommending it, it's actually an awfull way, as it might be a bit confusing. Presumably, you won't be the only one "evaluating" this code, and once you work in teams you prefer doing it in a standardized way (which would be the first way)

Comment: @Icepickle "Hey markokstate, I don't advocate stabbing yourself in the chest, but here's a really sharp knife" ;-P

Comment: @Equalsk Precisely, if so many people say he shouldn't then... :) But who am I to stop him

Answer (score 1):

`collection.First(x => [function]);`

is the same as writing

`collection.Where(x => [function]).First();`

LINQ is a query language, so is used for filtering, aggregating and projecting, rather than mutating. As you've found, there isn't an overload of First() except that which takes a predicate for filtering.

What you were doing in your first part of the example is the correct usage, there isn't a LINQ statement out of the box that will do what you're asking in the way that you would like to write it (and also nothing wrong with doing things the way that you have in your first usage).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the ugliest approach possible, but it's possible, indeed: :-D

```
people.First(x =>
{
    x.FirstName = "john";
    x.LastName = "doe";
    return true;
});
```

`First()` needs a predicate to filter the list, so it must be evaluated to `bool`. As long as you return `true`, it's going to work.

Returning `false` throws `InvalidOperationException`, with message: `Sequence contains no matching element`.

Comment: I know! Not sure if I'm proud or ashamed of that...  =D

Answer (score 0):

I already mentioned in the comment using LINQ - which is designed for *querying* items, not for *manipulating* them - to do what you've described is totally wrong and not recommended.

Of course you could write your own extension-method:

```
public static class MyWierdExtensions
{
    public static void ExecuteOnFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, Action<T> exec)
    {
        var element = source.First(predicate);
        exec(element);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to call it:

```
myEnumerable.ExecuteOnFirst(x => x.Id == 1, x => x.MyProperty = 3);
```

Or even - as you want:

```
people.ExecuteOnFirst(x => x.Id == 1, x => 
{
    x.FirstName = "john";
    x.LastName = "doe";
}
```

However I doubt you get any improvement by writing that kind of code. I'd strongly recommend to stay with your current approach: get the item using `First(predicate)` and then manipulate it by accessing the properties setters.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right, you should use your first approach. But if you want something fancy you could use

```
people.Take(1).ForEach(x => 
{
    x.FirstName = "john";
    x.LastName = "doe";
});
```